# C# Serial Port Issue

Tags: c#, resources, serial-port, wmi, gsm

I am trying to create a terminal much like Hyperterminal to talk to a GSM modem (open AT Sierra wireless sl8080). The modem can  reset randomly or by command being sent to the comm port. When the modem resets all communication is lost. I am using

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
}
```

To read from the device. but after a reset i can do anything and get nothing back.

If i try and read after a reset i get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The port is closed.
```

If i reset, then close port i get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The requested resource is in use.
```

I cannot recover from this state with out closing the application totally. I have been trying to solve this problem for over a year. I have come up with lots of other solutions. Mainly using Python and Java/RXTX which handle the resets from the device flawlessly. I am really stumped here its more of a personal challenge to figure this out now.

I tried using WMI to detect unplugs of usb devices and close the commport but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disposing the SerialPort object instead of closing it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived.aspx

> If a SerialPort object becomes blocked during a read operation, do not abort the thread. Instead, either close the base stream or dispose of the SerialPort object.

Comment: I have, also with the same result. Always have to close the application, and sometimes unplug the USB from the device for it to not say device is not functioning properly.

Comment: Is the object already disposed?
ALso I found this article which you might have already seen.  Seems to be some errors with .net. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89944715-8549-4fc9-86ec-7dd92b707786/serialport-unplug-and-plug)